# Copy 8000 lines of 4 column text over SSH

Tags: microsoft-excel, ssh, putty

I want to copy to my windows 7 clipboard for insertion into excel.

The file is a textfile on SSH. I can use vim to look at it, and I have tried gg"*yG, but it did not copy to the windows clipboard for pasting into excel.

Is there any other avenue of going from text file of column data over SSH to excel? Or maybe there is a tool I can use to generate graphs (scatter plots) of the different data sitting on the SSH machine?

Any advice would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SCP to copy the contents of the file. <del>If the file is too big to download, first get the data that you want into a file, then SCP that over.</del> (I see you just want the contents of the file)

Comment: mm golden thank you. winSCP is an awesome tool.